# Как дать имя выборке данных для дальнейшего обращения к ней Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть выборка данных

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE TABLE1.COLUMN1=1
```

Как мне правильно присвоить псевдоним, чтобы далее в этом же запросе я мог к ней обращаться ?
Т.е. эта выборка у меня будет идти как отдельная таблица или что-то вроде этого и я хочу к ней джойнить подобные выборки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  with table_alias as
  ( 
      SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE TABLE1.COLUMN1=1
  )

  select * from table_aliase;
```

Answer (score 0):

так же при необходимости вы можете подготовить "на лету" несколько таких выборок подряд и использовать их в конечном результирующем запросе. для примера:

```
with alias1 as
(
SELECT value1, value2 FROM TABLE1 WHERE TABLE1.COLUMN1=1
), 
alias2 as 
(
SELECT value3, value4 FROM TABLE2 WHERE TABLE1.COLUMN1=1
),
alias3 as 
(
SELECT value5, value6 FROM TABLE3 WHERE TABLE1.COLUMN1=1

select value1, value2 from alias1 a1
join alias2 a2 on a1.value1 = a2.value3
join alias3 a3 on a2.value3 = a3.value5
where a3.value6 < 100
```